# What is id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false used for?

Tags: android

I am working on a Java app and I know that all apps must include in build.gradle (app level) plugins
the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
  }
```

But what about build.gradle (project level)plugins?
Do all apps need to include `id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false`in the build.gradle (project level)plugins? How can I know if my app needs to include `id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false` in the build.gradle (project level)plugins? I don't understand what this is used for.. My app has worked fine always without `id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false`, but I have seen that some apps include this. What is the reason and use of including `id("com.android.application") version "7.2.0" apply false` in the build.gradle (project level)plugins?